# Red divider resistors for 5050 RGB strip coming from WS2811 chip

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, rgb, ws2811

To split up a WS2811 data signal into discrete 5050 RGB 12V LED signals, I followed the example on the WS2811 datasheet and hooked up its outputs to a separate power supply.

[image: WS2811 datasheet example]

This example shows one divider resistor on the red LEDs which is how I built [my circuit](https://github.com/CXgamer/Aura-sync-splitter). After doing research, [I discovered that 5050 LED strips actually require a resistor for every color](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/48526/163043). So now I'm wondering if I built my circuit wrongly.

The 5050 LED strips are usually not very long, varying from 2 LEDs to [24 LEDs](https://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?area=en&pid=740) in total. Should I assume these components have their resistors built in already? Should I still add additional resistors and what value should they be? Or should I only add resistors to plain RGB LEDs which I will hook up?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the electrical characteristics of the WS2811:

[image: electrical characteristics of the WS2811]

And here's that of the 5050 RGB spec:

[image: electrical characteristics of the 5050 RGB]

Comment: Your build is correct. You don't need a resistor in each string of LEDs. The resistor RR is added only to increase the effective Vf of the RED LEDs used. This reduces the power dissipation for the RED channel CC output regulator.

Comment: @JackCreasey Many thanks for explaining! I calculated I'll need resistors of around 310 Ω.

Comment: 310 Ohms is correct